# Функции высшего порядка

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток

Помогите решить задачку:
Нужно написать аналог метода every. 
"Создайте функцию every, она должна принимать первым аргументом массив чисел (обязательно проверьте что передан массив) вторым аргументом callback 
функция должна возвращать true или false в зависимости от результата вызова callback (проверить число больше 5). Callback  должен принимать один элемент массива, его индекс в массиве и весь массив." 
Всем спасибо

Comment: И как помочь - код за вас написать?

Comment: вы сами пытались что-то сделать?

Comment: да, пыталась, но, к сожалению, безуспешно

Answer (score 1):

Пример полифилла можно найти [в справке по функции `every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill)

```
if (!Array.prototype.every) {
  Array.prototype.every = function(callbackfn, thisArg) {
    'use strict';
    var T, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
    }

    // 1. Положим O равным результату вызова ToObject над значением
    //    this, переданным в качестве аргумента.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Положим lenValue равным результату вызова внутреннего метода Get
    //    объекта O с аргументом "length".
    // 3. Положим len равным ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. Если IsCallable(callbackfn) равен false, выкинем исключение TypeError.
    if (typeof callbackfn !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    // 5. Если thisArg присутствует, положим T равным thisArg; иначе положим T равным undefined.
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = thisArg;
    }

    // 6. Положим k равным 0.
    k = 0;

    // 7. Пока k < len, будем повторять
    while (k < len) {

      var kValue;

      // a. Положим Pk равным ToString(k).
      //   Это неявное преобразование для левостороннего операнда в операторе in
      // b. Положим kPresent равным результату вызова внутреннего метода
      //    HasProperty объекта O с аргументом Pk.
      //   Этот шаг может быть объединён с шагом c
      // c. Если kPresent равен true, то
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Положим kValue равным результату вызова внутреннего метода Get
        //    объекта O с аргументом Pk.
        kValue = O[k];

        // ii. Положим testResult равным результату вызова внутреннего метода Call
        //     функции callbackfn со значением T в качестве this и списком аргументов,
        //     содержащим kValue, k и O.
        var testResult = callbackfn.call(T, kValue, k, O);

        // iii. Если ToBoolean(testResult) равен false, вернём false.
        if (!testResult) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      k++;
    }
    return true;
  };
}
```

Comment: спасибо Вам большое!))

Answer (score -3):

```
Array.prototype.every = (..arg) => {
   this.every(...arg);
}
```

Comment: бесконечная рекурсия? :-) да и результат не возвращается.

Comment: Я так думаю, это ответ тролля))